# How can I make my code more modular in SML?

Tags: sml

I am programming in SML. My function takes an integer and then splices it into a list with a comma. For example digits 12345 -> [1,2.3,4,5]. My question is how do I make my code more modular. I kind of hardcoded my code. I would like it to work for an infinite amount of integers.

```ml
fun digits(m:int) =
  if m <10 then
    [m]
  else if m < 100 then
    [m div 10] @ [m mod 10]
  else if m > 100 andalso m < 1000 then
    [(m div 10) div 10] @[(m div 10) mod 10] @ [m mod 10]
  else if m > 1000 andalso m < 10000 then
    [((m div 10) div 10) div 10] @ [((m div 10) div 10) mod 10] @ [(m div 10) mod 10] @ [m mod 10]
  else if m > 10000 andalso m < 100000 then
    [(((m div 10) div 10) div 10) div 10] @ [((m div 10) div 10) div 10 mod 10] @ [((m div 10) div 10) mod 10] @ [(m div 10) mod 10] @ [m mod 10]
  else if m > 100000 andalso m < 1000000 then
    [((((m div 10) div 10) div 10) div 10) div 10] @ [(((((m div 10) div 10) div 10) div 10) mod 10) mod 10] @ [((m div 10) div 10) div 10 mod 10] @ [((m div 10) div 10) mod 10] @ [(m div 10) mod 10] @ [m mod 10]
  else if m > 1000000 andalso m < 10000000 then
    [(((m div 10) div 10) div 10) div 10 div 10 div 10] @ [(((m div 10) div 10) div 10) div 10 div 10 mod 10] @ [((m div 10) div 10) div 10 mod 10]@ [((m div 10) div 10) mod 10] @ [(m div 10) mod 10] @ [m mod 10]                                               
  else
    [(m div 10) div 10] @ [(m div 10) mod 10] @ [m mod 10]
```

Comment: May be it's just me.. but while programming (functional or otherwise), ... infinite amount of integers ... is confounding. `any integer` etc are more suitable and appropriate.. just a thought of mine.. rest is all up to you.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the problem you're trying to solve. There's no way you can hard-code all the possibilities.

Let's consider a basic example: a single digit number. Clearly for any input less than 10 the result is just that number in a list.

```ml
fun digits m =
  if m < 10 then
    [m]
```

If the number is greater than 10, it could be two digits, or it could be more. We don't know. But can we find the smallest digit?

```ml
fun smallestDigit m =
  if m < 10 then
    m
  else
    m mod 10
```

So if we call `smallestDigit 123` we get `3`.

And if we `123 div 10` we get `12`. Turns out we get `2` if we call `smallestDigit 12`. We just need to repeat this until we've got all of our digits. In functional programming, this repetition is typically achieved with *recursion*.

So let's put that together using recursion. What's critical is that we have an exit condition that stops the recursion, and that the other case converges toward that exit condition.

```ml
fun digits m =
  if m < 10 then
    [m]
  else 
    let
      val smallestDigit = m mod 10
      val remainingDigits = m div 10
    in
      digits remainingDigits @ [smallestDigit]
    end
```

For efficiency's sake we can use `::` instead of `@` with an accumulator.

While the below achieves the goal of making the function tail-recursive, an integer is not going to be big enough that a stack overflow should be a real concern. More importantly, this avoids repeated calls to `@` which would give the previous examples O(n^2) runtime complexity, instead yielding an O(n) runtime complexity.

```
fun digits(n) =
  let 
    fun digits'(n, acc) =
      if n < 10 then n::acc
      else digits'(n div 10, (n mod 10)::acc)
  in
    digits'(n, [])
  end;
```