# How to solve a Digital Root using SML

Tags: sml

I am having trouble with writing a function that will calculate a digital root of an integer. Consider the process of taking a number 'n', adding its digits, then adding the digits
of the number derived from it, etc., until the remaining number has only one digit.
The final single-digit number is called the digital root of 'n'. For example, the sequence obtained from the starting number 6381 is (6381, 18, 9), so 6381 has a digital root of 9.
My code:

```
fun digits(m:int) =
  if m < 10 then
    [m]
  else 
    let
      val smallestDigit = m mod 10
      val remainingDigits = m div 10
    in
      digits remainingDigits @ [smallestDigit]
    end
   

fun sum(ints) =
    if null ints then 0
    else
    (hd ints) + sum(tl ints)                              
                              
fun digitalRoot(i:int) =
    let
       val results = sum(digits i)
    in
       results
    end
```

My code only partially works. It gets 18 but I am having trouble with also getting the sum of 18.

Comment: Consider the answer [in the earlier question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69146566/how-can-i-make-my-code-more-modular-in-sml) you're directly using code from. If we need to repeat an action until some condition is true, what technique is used?

Comment: I think the point you didn't gather from the explanation of the process is that the final result is the digital root of all the numbers in the sequence; `digitalRoot 6381 = digitalRoot 18 = digitalRoot 9 = 9`. (Use recursion.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(* Function to extract the digits of an integer and return them as a list *)
fun digits(m:int) =
  if m < 10 then
    [m]
  else 
    let
      val smallestDigit = m mod 10
      val remainingDigits = m div 10
    in
      digits remainingDigits @ [smallestDigit]
    end

(* Function to calculate the sum of the integers in a list *)
fun sum(ints) =
    if null ints then 0
    else
    (hd ints) + sum(tl ints)

(* Function to calculate the digital root of an integer *)
fun digitalRoot(i:int) =
    let
       val results = sum(digits i)
    in
       if results < 10 then
           results
       else
           digitalRoot results
    end
```

Your answer was missing recursion.