# Find the subset of a list

Tags: sml

I am writing a function in SML that finds the subset of two integer sets. For example, `subset([1,5],[1,3,5])` should return `true`. I am having a little trouble with writing this function. My question is how should I go about writing this recursively.
Here is my function:

```ml
fun subset(lst1,lst2) = true
  |  subset(a::;lst1,lst2) =
       if member(a,lst2) then subset(lst1,lst2)
       else false;
```

Comment: As I suggested in response to your last question, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69146719/15261315) on recursion you took code directly from. Please show us an attempt at recursively solving this problem and we can answer questions on specific errors.

Comment: You're kind of on the right track, but `ls1` is a subset of `ls2` if all its elements are members of `ls2`, not if `ls1` itself is. Think about the case when `lst1` is the empty set, and the case when it isn't (i.e. has at least one member).

Comment: Also, does order matter?

Comment: I edited my code to use recursion. I am getting some errors with it though. Also, the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, following the comments, it appears that you want a predicate that's true if any one of the lists is a subset of the other.

This is tricky to do all at once; recursing over two lists simultaneously gets convoluted quickly.

Instead, let's fix your code and make it true if and only if `lst1` is a subset of `lst2`.

Then we can use this to implement the desired function:

```
fun either_subset(xs, ys) = subset(xs, ys) orelse subset(ys, xs)
```

Your first pattern matches all pairs, and pattern matches are attempted in the order they are written, so the result is always `true`.
You can fix this in two ways; either make the first case more specific and matching only the empty list,

```
fun subset([],lst2) = true
```

or rearrange the clauses so the first case matches any non-empty list,

```
fun subset(a::lst1,lst2) =
       if member(a,lst2) then subset(lst1,lst2)
       else false
  | subset(lst1,lst2) = true
```

You can also simplify this - `if e1 then e2 else false` is equivalent to `e1 andalso e2`, and when you don't use the names of a pattern you can use the wildcard pattern `_`:

```
fun subset(x::xs, ys) = member(x, ys) andalso subset(xs, ys)
  | subset _ = true
```

or

```
fun subset ([], _) = true
  | subset (x::xs, ys) = member(x, ys) andalso subset(xs, ys)
```

Comment: I know it's a subjective thing, but it always _feels right_ to me to have that "base" case for recursion expressed first.